# Add captured video in chat view

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

Am using JSQMessageViewController for chatting,while capturing the video it is saved in the photo album,i can't add it in to the chatview,if am trying to add the video means that video displayed in the png format.So could you please any one help me to solve this issue,How to add the capture the video from the chatview using JSQMessageViewController.After that i would like to upload the video in the chatview is using the API.Every captured video will be saved and added to the API and display the ChatView.

Comment: in this you have to create a thumbnail image of your video and send it to your chat table and after it send it your data base throw api otherwise your application crash

Comment: Yeah you correct,so please can you attach the sample piece of code,because it is may be useful.

Comment: i dont have that code now but i give you simple idea try it and if your want code for create thumbnail then i can send you

Comment: okay thank you,i checked for adding thumbail code.okay simply guide me.

Comment: i will try check it

Answer (score 0):

**This code is only for create a thumbnail that you want to display in chat**

```
YOURIMAGEVIEW.image = [SELF imageFromVideoUrl:@"GIVE HERE URL OF VIDEO"]; 

+(UIImage *)imageFromVideoUrl : (NSURL *)videoUrl
{

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoUrl];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    CMTime time = [asset duration];
    time.value = 0;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

    return thumbnail;
}
```

When you display this thumbnail in chat and in background call your api that upload a video into your server database . hope that you are clear with my this answer and got a idea what task actually you do.

Happy Coding.

Comment: @PreethaPreetha what kind of problem you face now ?

Comment: before that am adding this code,capturing picture and add picture working the correctly image format,but now am it is in video format.

Comment: but now adding the code everything in video format...this is an issue am faced

Comment: @PreethaPreetha just update your question with one ui that shows your chat with video thumbnail

Comment: @PreethaPreetha in your library its already one class that create a thumbnail and its display in tableview

Comment: @PreethaPreetha then approve my answer and give up vote thank you.